What does the suffix "S" in Pantone color names mean?
While preparing some graphical document for our club, I asked what Pantone Colors has been used when producing certain products. I was given "Pantone 195 S", and "Pantone 194 CS".
I seem to understand the meaning of suffix "C" to mean "coated", versus "U" to mean "uncoated". This refers to how the color would look like when printing on uncoated vesus coated paper. Don't need more details on this.
However, I was not able to find what suffix "S" means. Can anyone tell?

Pantone color suffixes are:

C (Coated): for colors printed on coated (glossy or shiny) paper.

U (Uncoated): colors printed on uncoated paper, which absorbs more ink.

TCX: Textile Cotton eXtended (for cotton fabrics)

TPX: Textile Paper eXtended (for fabrics)

TPG: Lacquer coated visual representation of our FHI Textile Cotton (TCX) system

TPM: Visual representation of 200 metallic finishes

PQ: Plastic Standard Chips (large plastic chips)

Q or T: Plastics Selector Chips

SP: for skin tones


There's a very comprehensive list of Pantone codes here.
CS and S are not standard suffixes in Pantone's guides. It might refer to a custom or proprietary variation used in certain industries.
Perhaps it's CP? Pantone CP refers to the Pantone ColorBridge (CP - Coated Process) color matching system. It's a subset of Pantone colors that have been adapted for both print and digital (screen) use.

Where did you find this information?  I can find no reference on the Pantone site for M, S, or CS ever having been used in the Pantone Matching System (PMS).

@BillyKerr I got duped by some AI-generated site on CS and S. I fixed the answer with info from the official Pantone site.

Yeah I thought that might be the issue, and your edit is definitely an improvement. However, as far as I know, Pantone (PMS) has never used the M suffix either, so I'd remove that one too. For PMS it's really only C or U.
